# Dealing with large integers without BigInteger Library in Algorithm contests

Tags: c#, algorithm, biginteger

Problem: Topcoder SRM 170 500

Consider a sequence {x0, x1, x2, ...}. A relation that defines some term xn in terms of previous terms is called a recurrence relation. A linear recurrence relation is one where the recurrence is of the form xn = c(k-1) * x(n-1) + c(k-2) * x(n-2) + ... + c(0) * x(n-k)
where all the c(i) are real-valued constants, k is the length of the recurrence relation, and n is an arbitrary positive integer which is greater than or equal to k.
You will be given a int[] coefficients, indicating, in order, c(0), c(1), ..., c(k-1). You will also be given a int[] initial, giving the values of x(0), x(1), ..., x(k-1), and an int N. Your method should return xN modulo 10.

More specifically, if coefficients is of size k, then the recurrence relation will be
xn = coefficients[k - 1] * xn-1 + coefficients[k - 2] * xn-2 + ... + coefficients[0] * xn-k.

For example, if coefficients = {2,1}, initial = {9,7}, and N = 6, then our recurrence relation is xn = xn-1 + 2 * xn-2 and we have x0 = 9 and x1 = 7. Then x2 = x1 + 2 * x0 = 7 + 2 * 9 = 25, and similarly, x3 = 39, x4 = 89, x5 = 167, and x6 = 345, so your method would return (345 modulo 10) = 5.

Constraints:
- Code must run in less than or equal to 2 seconds
- Memory utilization must not exceed 64 MB

My attempted Solution:

```
class RecurrenceRelation
{

    public int moduloTen(int[] coefficients, int[] initial, int N)
    {
        double xn = 0; int j = 0;
        int K = coefficients.Length;
        List<double> xs = new List<double>(Array.ConvertAll<int, double>(initial,
        delegate(int i)
        {
            return (double)i;
        })); 
        if (N < K)
            return negativePositiveMod(xs[N]);
        while (xs.Count <= N)
        {
            for (int i = xs.Count - 1; i >= j; i--)
            {
                xn += xs[i] * coefficients[K--];
            }
            K = coefficients.Length;
            xs.Add(xn);
            xn = 0;
            j++;
        }
        return negativePositiveMod(xs[N]);
    }
    public int negativePositiveMod(double b)
    {
        while (b < 0)
        {
            b += 10;
        }
        return (int)(b % 10);
    }
}
```

My problem with this solution is the precision of the double representation, and since I can't use a third party library or the BigInteger library in .NET for this SRM, i need to find a way of solving it without them. I suspect I could use recursion but I'm a little clueless on how to go about that.

Here is a test case that shows when my code works and when it doesn't

{2,1}, {9,7}, 6 - Successfully returns 5
{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 654 - Unsuccessfully returns 8 instead of 5 due to precision of double type

Can anyone help me figure this out? I was going to consider using arrays to store the values but it is a little bit beyond me especially on how to cater for multiplication and still be within the time and space complexity set out in the problem. Perhaps my entire approach is wrong? I'd appreciate some pointers and direction (not fully fleshed out answers) answers please.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this more fit for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: i don't think so, i'm interested in approach and discussion on the topics involved in solving the problem. But no harm in posting it there I think. Will do in tick.

Comment: Hang in. It is discouraged to cross-post. It was just my idea, maybe others don't agree.

Comment: @PhamTrung coeeficient array is fixed. Initial on the other hand grows as we look for the Nth term. There recurrence relation is determined by the coefficient array and the values in xs (which contains initial as well). these values can be huge! several times larger than what int can store (see test case two and you'll see why) hence the reason for using double which stores values as for example 1.23438457934759843E102. However I need more precision (upto say 100 decimal places) in order to get the right answer. int cannot do that without overflow.

Comment: @TheJackal I don't see any reason why you need to work with big number, as you only need to return xn modulo 10, which also mean you only need to work with those number less than 10.

Comment: @TheJackal and if you look at the editorial for this [srm](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm170), they solved that in similar manner.

Comment: are you sure for the testcase with  {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 654 ? I am getting 1. Maybe my solution is wrong still.

Comment: Have updated my example code. getting the same results as you'd expect now.

Comment: A `double` floating point (in all cases you are likely to meet) has less precision than your `int64_t` or your common or garden `long long` (on most machines these days).  Since the recurrence relation is all integers, you need an exact answer... so floating point cannot be the answer to the range issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that we only need to return the modulo 10 of `xn`.

We also need to know that if `a = b + c`, we have `a % 10 = (b % 10 + c % 10) %10.`

And `a = b*c`, so we also have `a % 10 = (b %10 * c % 10) % 10;`

So, for

```
xn = c(k-1) * x(n-1) + c(k-2) * x(n-2) + ... + c(0) * x(n-k) 
            = a0 + a1 + .... + an
```

(with a0 = c(k - 1)*x(n-1), a1 = ...)

we have `xn % 10 = (a0 % 10 + a1 % 10 + ...)%10`

And for each `ai = ci*xi`, so `ai % 10 = (ci % 10 * xi % 10)% 10`.

So by doing all of these math calculations, we can avoid to use double and keep the result in manageable size.

Comment: many thanks pham for explaining this to me. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Pham has answered, the trick is to realize that you only need to return a modulo, thereby bypassing the problem of overflow. Here is my quick attempt. I use a queue to put in the last result xN, and evict the oldest one.

```
    static int solve(int[] coefficients, int[] seed, int n)
    {
        int k = coefficients.Count();
        var queue = new Queue<int>(seed.Reverse().Take(k).Reverse());

        for (int i = k; i <= n; i++)
        {

            var xn = coefficients.Zip(queue, (x, y) => x * y % 10).Sum() % 10;
            queue.Enqueue(xn);
            queue.Dequeue();
        }

        return (int) (queue.Last() );

    }
```

Edit:
Getting the same results as you expect, however I don't guarantee that there is no bug in this example.

Comment: Wasn't aware that k can be < n. This version should work also when coefficients are less than the seed.

Comment: this will fail for negative xn, you need to handle -xn (by addition) to get correct modulus;

Comment: if negative coeffients are allowed you could maybe use `(x, y) => ((x * y % 10) + 10) % 10)`. Adding 10 to a negative number greater than -10 makes it positive again. However, my answer just outlines a possible solution as you also mentioned performance issues with your solution. I don't guarantee that is it bug free, but is a place for you to start. I also don't handle the case where N < K